# open form submit in light box

Tags: jquery, forms, lightbox, onsubmit

I have been looking everywhere for an answer to this and just can't seem to find anything that will work for me.

I have a form at the moment that submits the data to interspire email marketer. When the form is submitted it takes you to a thank you page. At the moment I have got the thank you page to open up in a pop up window so you don't leave the main website page.

Popups look old and ugly so I would like it to open in a light box.

The code I have so far is:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.blackbambooliquids.com/email/form.php?form=1" id="frmSS1"
      onsubmit="return CheckForm1(this) && target_popup(this);">

    ....form fields....

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>

<script>
    function target_popup(form) {
        window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
    }
</script>
```

The action target address `http://www.blackbambooliquids.com/email/form.php?form=1` is what I would like to show inside the light box.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to use jquery-ui dialog widget for this.

Comment: why you not use ajax? You can check the response and use a response function to open lightbox

Comment: ive tried using ajax for this before but couldnt get it to work it just kept taking me to the thank you page. any ideas how i can implement the 2 sugestions?